# Is it possible to use AJAX data within "fixheadertable" plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fixheadertable

I'm using this plugin on a project http://www.tablefixedheader.com/ but I need to put some dynamic data while creating the tables.

The Js code that builds the table is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax({
            url: 'dialogs/WMS/mytable.php',
            success: function(data) {
                $('.maintab<?php echo $varc ?>
                ').html(data).fixheadertable({
                   colratio : [45, 24, 24, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150 ],
                   zebra : true,
                   sortable : true,
                   sortedColId : 3,
                   resizeCol : true,
                   height  : 150,
                   pager : true,
                   sortType : ['integer', 'string', 'string', 'string', 'string', 'date']
                });
                            }
    });
</script>
```

I need to include some parameters. What I tried:

Example 1 (no success)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $.ajax({
      url:'dialogs/mytable.php?columns='<?php echo $column ?>,
      type: 'post',
      success: function(data) {
      $('.maintab<?php echo $varc ?>
       ').html(data).fixheadertable({
       colratio : [45, 24, 24, 180, 180, 180, 180, 180,180, 180, 180, 180, 180, 180]
       zebra : true,
       sortable : true,
       sortedColId : 3,
       resizeCol : true,
       height  : 150,
       pager : true,
       sortType : ['integer', 'string', 'string', 'string', 'string', 'date']
       });
       }
       });
     </script>
```

Example 2 (no success)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $.ajax({
      url:'dialogs//mytable.php?columns='<?php $column ?>,
      type: 'post',
      success: function(data) {
      $('.maintab<?php echo $varc ?>
       ').html(data).fixheadertable({
       colratio : [45, 24, 24, 180, 180, 180, 180, 180,180, 180, 180, 180, 180, 180],
       zebra : true,
       sortable : true,
       sortedColId : 3,
       resizeCol : true,
       height  : 150,
       pager : true,
       sortType : ['integer', 'string', 'string', 'string', 'string', 'date']
       });
       }
       });
     </script>
```

Example 3 (no success)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $.ajax({
  url:'dialogs/mytable.php',
   data: {
   columns: <?php echo $column ?>,
  }
  type: 'post',
  success: function(data) {
  $('.maintab<?php echo $varc ?>
   ').html(data).fixheadertable({
   colratio : [45, 24, 24, 180, 180, 180, 180, 180,180, 180, 180, 180, 180, 180],
   zebra : true,
   sortable : true,
   sortedColId : 3,
   resizeCol : true,
   height  : 150,
   pager : true,
   sortType : ['integer', 'string', 'string', 'string', 'string', 'date']
   });
   }
   });
 </script>
```

Example 4 (no success)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $.ajax({
  url:'dialogs/mytable.php',
   data: {
   columns: <?php $column ?>,
  }
  type: 'post',
  success: function(data) {
  $('.maintab<?php echo $varc ?>
   ').html(data).fixheadertable({
   colratio : [45, 24, 24, 180, 180, 180, 180, 180,180, 180, 180, 180, 180, 180],
   zebra : true,
   sortable : true,
   sortedColId : 3,
   resizeCol : true,
   height  : 150,
   pager : true,
   sortType : ['integer', 'string', 'string', 'string', 'string', 'date']
   });
   }
   });
 </script>
```

Had no answers from developer and nothing similar found on forums. Anyone knows how to proceed?

Comment: Shouldn't it be: `url:'dialogs/mytable.php?columns=<?php echo $column ?>',` ??? Or `url:'dialogs/mytable.php?columns='+<?php echo $column ?>;` if column is a number should work too

Comment: thanks for your quick reply, but still not working :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the answer. To whom uses this plugin and needs database to push data, with AJAX data, you should proceed with this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $.ajax({
  url:'dialogs/mytable.php',
   data:{view: view,
        columns : '<?php echo $columns; ?>',
        },
  type: 'post',
  success: function(data) {
  $('.maintab<?php echo $varc ?>
   ').html(data).fixheadertable({
   colratio : [45, 24, 24, 180, 180, 180, 180, 180,180, 180, 180, 180, 180, 180],
   zebra : true,
   sortable : true,
   sortedColId : 3,
   resizeCol : true,
   height  : 150,
   pager : true,
   sortType : ['integer', 'string', 'string', 'string', 'string', 'date']
   });
   }
   });
 </script>
```

By the way, thanks for everyone who tried to help this issue :)